# Is there a way to print out the itirated contents of my while loop all at once? Instead of one at a time?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, user-input

I'm using while loop to create policies. However, I would like the policies to be
printed out all at once at the end. Currently, I am only able to get them to print one by one.

I tried implementing a list to try and store information within it to call it out later. However, I believe I'm reaching beyond my current knowledge. I am new to python and programming in general. I'm open to any suggestions or advice.

## This is for Python3.

## What I currently have is the following

```
NumberOfPolicies = int(input ('How many Policies will you create?: '))
counter = 0
while counter < NumberOfPolicies:
    PartA = input('Paste in Part A of Policy: ')
    PartB = input ("Paste in Part B of Policy: ")
    PartC = input("Paste in Part C of policy: ")    
    NumberOfPolicies -= 1
    print ('\n it is ' + PartA + ' that will be translated to '+ 
    PartB+':'+PartC+'\n')
```

The output is below. I would like all the questions to be asked first and for the output to be spat out all at once at the end.

```
How many Policies will you create?: 2
Paste in Part A of Policy: 20
Paste in Part B of Policy: 20
Paste in Part C of policy: 20

 it is 20 that will be translated to 20:20

Paste in Part A of Policy: 30
Paste in Part B of Policy: 30
Paste in Part C of policy: 30

 it is 30 that will be translated to 30:30
```

Comment: store the input inside a list, then iterate on that

Comment: That is a perfect solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: if you like the solution, please click on the "v" on the left side of the solution so I get rewarded for my modest efforts ;-)

Comment: Done! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this could do :

```
number_of_policies = int(input('How many Policies will you create?: '))
policies = []

for i in range(number_of_policies):
    parts = {}    
    parts['a'] = input('Paste in Part A of Policy: ')
    parts['b'] = input('Paste in Part B of Policy: ')
    parts['c'] = input('Paste in Part C of policy: ')    
    policies.append(parts)

for policy in policies:
    print(f"\n it is {policy['a']} that will be translated to {policy['b']}:{policy['c']}\n")
```